# Unable to connect PN532 Board to Arduino Uno

Tags: nfc

I'm attempting to connect this [PN532 NFC Board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01I1J17LC) to an Arduino UNO using SPI. Currently my arduino is unable to recognize the board and I'm not sure whats the root of my issue. I'm using the Adafruit PN532 library and my program fails at trying to get the Firmwarm Version of the attached chip. I've attached the code and [pictures of the soldering and connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0hc2.jpg). One interesting note is the LED on the chip will turn on before I connect VCC. The LED will turn on as soon as plug in MOSI (Not sure if that is intended behavior). Any ideas on where my issue might be?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>

// If using the breakout with SPI, define the pins for SPI communication.
#define PN532_SCK  (13)
#define PN532_MISO (12)
#define PN532_MOSI (11)
#define PN532_SS   (10)

// Use this line for a breakout with a SPI connection:
Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SCK, PN532_MISO, PN532_MOSI, PN532_SS);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  nfc.begin();
  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Could not find board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

  Serial.print("Found Board");
  nfc.SAMConfig();
}


void loop(void) {
  uint8_t success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  
  uint8_t uidLength;                        

  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);

  if (success) {
    Serial.println("Found a card");
    }
    delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: MOSI pin and IRQ pin looks badly soldered ... could also be a reflection in a very good solder connection

Comment: you use the constructor for software SPI. use `Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SS);`. the SPI library knows the other pins